# Bootstrap carousel with multiple items and default carousel on the same page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in applying CSS in a specific carousel on the page.

When I try to apply CSS in `.carousel-inner .prev / .next` only to the second carousel does not work properly. If i remove `#secondCarousel` (at CSS selector) it works, but cause undesirable behavior in the first carousel.

The example of what I mean can be seen on the links below.

[Carousel default working](http://www.bootply.com/tFDV026had) | [Carousel with multiple items working](http://www.bootply.com/xrIugr2z30)

Anyone have any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: I would like to know why do you have to apply `left: 33%` in next and prev?

Comment: According to the logic of what has been implemented, next and prev are added temporarily during the transition of slides and 33% is what enables the transition occurs visually correct when I have 3 items per slide

Comment: Hi Victor, 

Could you explain exactly which behaviours carousel one and two should have?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the CSS there as well for the `#firstCarousel` because you take the CSS from it when you assign it to just the `#secondCarousel`. Either do this:

```
#secondCarousel .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
#secondCarousel .carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
#secondCarousel .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }
#firstCarousel .carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
#firstCarousel .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }
```

or leave a generic CSS set out like this:

```
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }
```