# Default carousel and multi item carousel on same page

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-4

I found same question, but I failed to make it work. ([Bootstrap carousel with multiple items and default carousel on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483776/bootstrap-carousel-with-multiple-items-and-default-carousel-on-the-same-page))

I want to combine default carousel(one image per slide) and for example
this one: https://www.codeply.com/go/s3I9ivCBYH

Here is my code: https://www.codeply.com/go/6AXxUSWcmV

I tried to change css, also tried to change names of classes, to be different from names of bootstrap classes, to put some IDs, but without success...

I'm working with bootstrap4

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: My fault, I forgot to post my code

Comment: Hey @nishikori, you can actually edit your post to add the code.

Comment: Yes, I did it. :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to have both type of carousels running on the same page, you just have to prefix all the additional styles that comes with the modified carousel to prevent the collision of the styles. In the example below I just prefixed the styles with the id of the “small” carousel.

```js
$('#small-carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 3;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
    
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
/* Note the `#small-carousel` prefixes */
/*@media (min-width: 768px) {*/
    /* show 3 items */
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .active,
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }
    
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
      position: relative;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.3333%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* left or forward direction */
    #small-carousel .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    #small-carousel .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    #small-carousel .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    #small-carousel .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
    #small-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    /* right or prev direction */
    #small-carousel .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    #small-carousel .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    #small-carousel .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    #small-carousel .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
/*}*/
```

```html
<!-- “Big” carousel -->
<div id="big-carousel" class="carousel slide mb-3" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/800x150/f5d0c5/fff&text=Big+1" alt="Big 1">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/800x150/d69f7e/fff&text=Big+2" alt="Big 2">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/800x150/774936/fff&text=Big+3" alt="Big 3">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#big-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#big-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

<!-- “Small” carousel with id="small-carousel" -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="small-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item col-4 active">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x200/729ea1/fff&text=Small+1" alt="Slide 1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x200/b5bd89/fff&text=Small+2" alt="Slide 2">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x200/dfbe99/fff&text=Small+3" alt="Slide 3">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x200/ec9192/fff&text=Small+4" alt="Slide 4">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x200/db5375/fff&text=Small+5" alt="Slide 5">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x200/596f62/fff&text=Small+6" alt="Slide 6">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-4">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="http://placehold.it/400x200/c3d898/fff&text=Small+7" alt="Slide 7">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#small-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#small-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I also did something like that, but without previous and next arrows on "small carousel". So this is improvement. :) Is it possible to make "small carousel" to slide "in circle"? Like here: codeply.com/go/s3I9ivCBYH Without waiting for 7th item to come to the end.

Comment: Your original code failed to use the css prefixes, so the main carousel was not working properly. Now that you have inserted the code above into your codeply, it obviously works.

Comment: To me the code at https://www.codeply.com/go/s3I9ivCBYH behaves the same as the one in my answer